# How do I run a cypher query on virtual nodes and relationships in Neo4j ceated using APOC?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a bunch of nodes and links with me. I want to do some pattern search upon this data. I don't want to create node in neo4j. Insead I want to run a cypher query on this data. So how to achieve this using APOC Virtual nodes and Relaionships?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot perform Cypher queries on virtual nodes and relationships.